# How to create JSON response with nested array

Tags: arrays, list, nested, salesforce, apex

I have a list which looks like this:

```
{
  "data1": "abcd",
  "data2": "efgh",
}
```

I'm trying to create a JSON response in this format by looping the above array and building the below:

```
{
  "id": "123456",
  "nestedArray": [
    {
      "data1": "abcd",
      "somedata": 1234
    },
    {
      "data2": "efgh",
      "somedata": 1234
    }
  ]
}
```

I've created a model to map the structure of the nested array:

```
public class nestedArray{
    public String data1;
    public Integer data2;

    public nestedArray(string data) {
        this.data1 = uri;
        this.data2 = 1234;
    }
}
```

But i'm stuck on how to build the final response, any pointers is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
JSON:

{
  "id": "123456",
  "nestedArray": [
    {
      "data1": "abcd",
      "somedata": 1234
    },
    {
      "data1": "efgh",
      "somedata": 1234
    }
  ]
}

Model:
public class Resp {

    public class NestedArray {
        public String data1;
        public Integer somedata;
    }

    public String id;
    public List<NestedArray> nestedArray;


    public static Resp parse(String json) {
        return (Resp) System.JSON.deserialize(json, Resp.class);
    }
}
```